# Can't clone() Texture

Tags: three.js, webgl

Basicly,

this works:

```
var expl1 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/explodes/expl1.png' );
this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: expl1, transparent:true, blending:THREE.AdditiveBlending });
```

And this doesnt...

```
var expl1 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/explodes/expl1.png' );
this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: expl1.clone(), transparent:true, blending:THREE.AdditiveBlending });
```

The problem is, i have multiple objects with this texture. I want to be able to change the texture offsets of 1 of the objects without the others changing also. That's why i need clone, but the cloned texture seems to be empty.

```
var expl1 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/explodes/expl1.png' );
```

this is only loaded once in a global variable. I could load a new texture each time i'm creating a new object, but because it's 700KB, it creates lag when loading the image.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

EDIT: `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture()` has been replaced by `loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(); loader.load()`.

---

This is likely because `new THREE.TextureLoader().load()` sets the `needsUpdate` flag for you, while cloning does not.

Do this, instead

```
var texture2 = texture1.clone();
texture2.needsUpdate = true;
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture2, ... } );
```

three.js r.75

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. But it seems that cloning is the same as loading a new texture, it's still laggy. Ah well, i'll come up with something. Thanks for helping me out here.

Comment: `three.module.js:20349 THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for update but image is undefined` getting this after clone and `needsUpdate= true` =(