# three.js - cloning textures and onLoad

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

My goal is to create a cube/box with a single texture but different repeat values for each of the sides. Working code is below:

```
var cubeMaker = function(w,h,d, tName)
{
    var g = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 50*w, 50*h, 50*d );

    var tx = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( tName );
    var ty = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( tName );
    var tz = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( tName );

    tx.wrapS = tx.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    ty.wrapS = ty.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    tz.wrapS = tz.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

    tx.repeat.set(d,h);
    ty.repeat.set(w,d);
    tz.repeat.set(w,h);

    var mx = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: tx} );
    var my = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: ty} );
    var mz = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: tz} );

    var mArray = [mx,mx,my,my,mz,mz];
    var m6 = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( mArray );

    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(g, m6);
    return cube;
}
```

However, it seems wasteful to load the texture three times.  Earlier, I instead tried passing a texture as an argument to the function (instead of a string representing the filename), as follows:

```
var cubeMaker = function(w,h,d, texture)
{
    ...
    var tx = texture.clone();
    var ty = texture.clone();
    var tz = texture.clone();
    ...
```

but then the textures didn't appear in the scene, only solid black images appeared in their place.  My best guess is that the texture image hadn't finished loading before the clone methods were called, and perhaps some kind of null value was copied instead.  Is there some way to use an onLoad method to wait long enough so that the clone function works as intended?

Note: I have tried the suggestion from [Can't clone() Texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705399/cant-clone-texture) but it does not solve my issue.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load your texture once, and move the rest of your code into the loader callback function. You also have to set the `needsUpdate` flag to `true` when you clone your texture.

```
var tx = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( tName, undefined, function() {

    var ty = tx.clone();
    ty.needsUpdate = true; // important!

    var tz = tx.clone();
    tz.needsUpdate = true; // important!

    tx.wrapS = tx.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    ty.wrapS = ty.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    tz.wrapS = tz.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

    tx.repeat.set( 1, 1 );
    ty.repeat.set( 2, 1 );
    tz.repeat.set( 2, 2 );

    var mx = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: tx } );
    var my = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: ty } );
    var mz = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: tz } );

    var mArray = [ mx, mx, my, my, mz, mz ];
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( mArray ) );
    scene.add( mesh );

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create then your texture outside of your function and just use this texture inside of your function, assigning it to special variable for each side? That way for sure you are going to load it just once.